# Solve taking a long time to solve a system of non linear equations

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, nonlinear

I am trying to to find steady states to a system and for that I tried the following code.  This is a system of 5 ODEs (`b,be,ei,eu,n` are the variables).

```
Assuming[{x1 > 0, x2 > 0, x3 > 0, x4 > 0, x5 > 0, x6 > 0, x7 > 0, 
  x8 > 0, x9 > 0, x10 > 0, x11 > 0, y > 0}, 
 Simplify[Solve[
   b[t]*(1 - (b[t] + be[t])) - x1*b[t]*eu[t] - 
      x2*b[t]*n[t]/(n[t] + b[t]) - x3*b[t] + 
      ei[t]*be[t]*(1 - (b[t] + be[t])) == 
     0 && (1 - ei[t])*be[t]*(1 - (b[t] + be[t])) + x1*b[t]*eu[t] - 
      x4*be[t]*n[t]/(n[t] + be[t]) == 0 && 
    x5*b[t]*eu[t] - x6*ei[t] + 
      x7*(1 - ei[t])*be[t]*(1 - (b[t] + be[t])) == 0 && 
    x8 - x5*b[t]*eu[t] - x8*eu[t] - 
      x7*(1 - ei[t])*be[t]*(1 - (b[t] + be[t])) == 
     0 && (x9 - x10*n[t])*(b[t] + be[t]) - x11*n[t] == 0 && 
    0 <= b[t] <= 1 && 0 <= be[t] <= 1 && 0 <= ei[t] <= 1 && 
    0 <= eu[t] <= 1 && 0 <= n[t] <= y, {b[t], be[t], ei[t], eu[t], 
    n[t]}, Reals]]]
```

But, Mathematica would run for a very long time without giving a solution (tried the above using `Reduce` and `NSolve` as well).

So, I thought of solving the equations by hand.
By setting `(x9 - x10*n[t])*(b[t] + be[t]) - x11*n[t] == 0` I can find `n` and then the plan is to substitute this to `(b + be)*(1 - (b + be)) - n*((x2*b/(n + b)) + (x4*be/(n + be))) - 
  x3*b == 0` and solve this for `b`, so I would get a solution for `b` in terms of `be`.

For this I tried out,

```
n = x9*(b + be)/(x11 + x10*(b + be));   
Assuming[{x9 > 0, x11 > 0,x10 > 0, x3 > 0, x2 > 0, x4 > 0}, 
     Simplify[Solve[(b + be)*(1 - (b + be)) - 
          n*((x2*b/(n + b)) + (x4*be/(n + be))) - x3*b == 0 && 
        0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= be <= 1, {b}, Reals]]]
```

and

```
n = x9*(b + be)/(x11 + x10*(b + be));
subdomain = 0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= be <= 1;
NSolve[subdomain && (b + be)*(1 - (b + be)) - 
    n*((x2*b/(n + b)) + (x4*be/(n + be))) - x3*b == 0, {b}, Reals]
```

But in both ways, Mathematica would run for a very long time and still wouldn't produce a result.

Can someone please tell me how to find an analytical solution to this system.

---

The solution outputs are based on the answer by  @bbgodfrey

How can I read this solution obtained from `Reduce`.
  So, is one solution is `(b == 0 && ei == (be (-1 + b + be) x7)/(-x6 + be (-1 + b + be) x7) && 
  eu == (be (-1 + b + ei - b ei) x7 + be^2 (x7 - ei x7) + x8)/(
   b x5 + x8))` with `n == ((b + be) x9)/(b x10 + be x10 + x11)`.
Then the other solution is

```
(((be == 0 && b > 0 && 
      ei x6 (b x5 + x8) == b x5 x8) || (0 < be < 
       1 && ((ei == (((-1 + be) be x7 + 
              b (-x5 + be x7)) x8)/(-(x6 - (-1 + be) be x7) x8 + 
            b (-x5 x6 + be x7 x8)) && (x5 == (be (-1 + b + be) x7)/b ||
             x6 < (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8) || 
            x6 > (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8)) && (b + be >= 
             1 || b > 0) && (b + be < 1 || 
            x6 < (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8) || b + be > 1 ||
             x6 > (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8))) || (x5 == (
           be (-1 + b + be) x7)/b && 
          x6 == (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(
           b x5 + x8) && ((b > 0 && b + be < 1) || 
            b + be > 1)))) || (be == 1 && 
      b > 0 && (ei == (b (x5 - x7) x8)/(b x5 x6 + x6 x8 - b x7 x8) || 
        x6 (b x5 + x8) == b x7 x8) && (x5 == x7 || 
        x6 (b x5 + x8) != b x7 x8))) && 
  eu == (be (-1 + b + be) x7 + ei (x6 - be (-1 + b + be) x7))/(b x5)) with same `n`?
```

I cannot understand how to read this part of the solution

```
((be == 0 && b > 0 && 
    ei x6 (b x5 + x8) == b x5 x8) || (0 < be < 
     1 && ((ei == (((-1 + be) be x7 + 
            b (-x5 + be x7)) x8)/(-(x6 - (-1 + be) be x7) x8 + 
          b (-x5 x6 + be x7 x8)) && (x5 == (be (-1 + b + be) x7)/b || 
          x6 < (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8) || 
          x6 > (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8)) && (b + be >= 1 ||
           b > 0) && (b + be < 1 || 
          x6 < (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8) || b + be > 1 || 
          x6 > (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8))) || (x5 == (
         be (-1 + b + be) x7)/b && 
        x6 == (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(
         b x5 + x8) && ((b > 0 && b + be < 1) || 
          b + be > 1)))) || (be == 1 && 
    b > 0 && (ei == (b (x5 - x7) x8)/(b x5 x6 + x6 x8 - b x7 x8) || 
      x6 (b x5 + x8) == b x7 x8) && (x5 == x7 || 
      x6 (b x5 + x8) != b x7 x8)))
```

In this part does it mean that,

```
eu == (be (-1 + b + be) x7 + ei (x6 - be (-1 + b + be) x7))/(b x5))) &&
  n == ((b + be) x9)/(b x10 + be x10 + x11)
```

and the other possible solutions can be
1) `(be == 0 && b > 0 && ei x6 (b x5 + x8) == b x5 x8)` or
2)

```
(be == 1 && 
  b > 0 && (ei == (b (x5 - x7) x8)/(b x5 x6 + x6 x8 - b x7 x8) || 
    x6 (b x5 + x8) == b x7 x8) && (x5 == x7 || 
    x6 (b x5 + x8) != b x7 x8)) or
```

3)

```
(0 < be < 
   1 && ((ei == (((-1 + be) be x7 + 
          b (-x5 + be x7)) x8)/(-(x6 - (-1 + be) be x7) x8 + 
        b (-x5 x6 + be x7 x8)) && (x5 == (be (-1 + b + be) x7)/b || 
        x6 < (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8) || 
        x6 > (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8)) && (b + be >= 1 || 
        b > 0) && (b + be < 1 || 
        x6 < (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8) || b + be > 1 || 
        x6 > (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8))) || (x5 == (
       be (-1 + b + be) x7)/b && 
      x6 == (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(
       b x5 + x8) && ((b > 0 && b + be < 1) || b + be > 1))))
```

Inside this 3rd solution there are several other possibilities that can happen,is it? But, how do I read off those solutions. Specially I don't understand the part of

```
(x5 == (be (-1 + b + be) x7)/b || 
  x6 < (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8) || 
  x6 > (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8))
```

Comment: `Reduce` almost certain can obtain a solution.  However, because this is a fifteenth order system, the computation will be very slow, and the results is unlikely to be simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I noted in an earlier comment, `Reduce` almost certainly can obtain a solution. However, because this is a fourteenth order system, the computation will be very slow, and the results is unlikely to be simple.  I have been running the general problem for about seven hours so far.

Here is a partial solution.  The five equations with `[t]` removed (unnecessary) and denominators cleared are,

```
eq = 
  b^3 + (-1 + be) be ei n + b^2 (-1 + be + be ei + n + eu x1 + x3) + 
    b (be^2 ei + be (ei (-1 + n) + n) + n (-1 + eu x1 + x2 + x3)) == 0 &&
  be^3 (-1 + ei) + be^2 (-1 + ei) (-1 + b + n) + b be eu x1 + b eu n x1 + 
    be n (1 + b (-1 + ei) - ei - x4) == 0 && 
  b eu x5 + b be (-1 + ei) x7 + (-1 + be) be ei x7 == ei x6 + (-1 + be) be x7 && 
  be (-1 + ei) x7 + be^2 (x7 - ei x7) + x8 == b eu x5 + b be (-1 + ei) x7 + eu x8 &&
  (b + be) (-n x10 + x9) == n x11
```

Now, solve for the three values, `{ei, eu, n}`,

```
seieun = Simplify[Reduce[eq[[3 ;; 5]], {ei, eu, n}, Reals], 
    {x1 > 0, x2 > 0, x3 > 0, x4 > 0, x5 > 0, x6 > 0, 
    x7 > 0, x8 > 0, x9 > 0, x10 > 0, x11 > 0, y > 0, 0 <= b <= 1, 0 <= be <= 1}]
```

which yields after several minutes,

```
(* ((b == 0 && ei == (be (-1 + b + be) x7)/(-x6 + be (-1 + b + be) x7) &&
   eu == (be (-1 + b + ei - b ei) x7 + be^2 (x7 - ei x7) + x8)/(b x5 + x8)) || 
  (((be == 0 && b > 0 && ei x6 (b x5 + x8) == b x5 x8) || (0 < be < 1 && 
  ((ei == (((-1 + be) be x7 + b (-x5 + be x7)) x8)/(-x6 x8 + (-1 + be) be x7 x8 + 
  b (-x5 x6 + be x7 x8)) && (x5 == (be (-1 + b + be) x7)/b || 
 x6 < (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8) || x6 > (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8)) &&
  (b + be >= 1 || b > 0) && (b + be < 1 || x6 < (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8) || 
  b + be > 1 || x6 > (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8))) || 
  (x5 == (be (-1 + b + be) x7)/b && x6 == (be (-1 + b + be) x7 x8)/(b x5 + x8) &&
  ((b > 0 && b + be < 1) || b + be > 1)))) || (be == 1 && b > 0 && 
  (ei == (b (x5 - x7) x8)/(b x5 x6 + x6 x8 - b x7 x8) || x6 (b x5 + x8) == b x7 x8) &&
  (x5 == x7 || x6 (b x5 + x8) != b x7 x8))) && 
  eu == (be (-1 + b + be) x7 + ei (x6 - be (-1 + b + be) x7))/(b x5))) && 
  n == ((b + be) x9)/(b x10 + be x10 + x11) *)
```

Examining this maze of options indicates that

```
n == ((b + be) x9)/(b x10 + be x10 + x11)
```

in all cases, as expected.  There are two solutions for `eu`:

```
eu == (be (-1 + b + ei - b ei) x7 + be^2 (x7 - ei x7) + x8)/(b x5 + x8)
```

with corresponding `ei == (be (-1 + b + be) x7)/(-x6 + be (-1 + b + be) x7)` and `b == 0`  Vanishing `b` appears to over-constrain the remaining two equations, although one cannot be certain without substituting into them the expressions for `{ei, eu, n}` and attempting to `Reduce` the resulting equations.  The second solution is

```
eu == (be (-1 + b + be) x7 + ei (x6 - be (-1 + b + be) x7))/(b x5)
```

with several solutions for `ei` and multiple constraints on the constants.  To proceed further, it is necessary to substitute each of these alternative solutions into the first two equations and attempt to solve them.

**Addendum - Quick Solution**

After thirty hours, the brute-force computation mentioned at the beginning of this answer still is running.  However, because the OP is interested only in solutions for arbitrary values of the constants (see comments below), assigning random values to the twelve constants and solving the resulting equations produces the correct answer in seconds.  For instance,

```
Thread[Rule[{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, y}, RandomInteger[100, 12]/10]]
Simplify[Reduce[eq /. %, {b, be, ei, eu, n}, Reals], {0 <= b <= 1, 0 <= be <= 1}]
(* {x1 -> 49/5, x2 -> 5/2, x3 -> 27/5, x4 -> 73/10, x5 -> 6, x6 -> 8, 
    x7 -> 29/5, x8 -> 83/10, x9 -> 7/10, x10 -> 14/5, x11 -> 12/5, y -> 33/10} *)
(* b == 0 && be == 0 && ei == 0 && eu == 1 && n == 0 *)
```

Repeating this computation several times with different random numbers produces the same results, as expected.  To emphasize, this result is not merely a correct answer, it is the only generally correct answer.

For completeness, this same result can be obtained from the first two lines of the block of solutions named `seieun` above:

```
nrule = seieun // Last // ToRules
eq1 = Map[Numerator, Together[eq[[1 ;; 2]] /. %], {2}] // Simplify;
(* {n -> ((b + be) x9)/(b x10 + be x10 + x11)} *)

erule = seieun // First // First // ToRules
Map[Numerator, Together[eq1 //. %], {2}] // Simplify;
Simplify[Reduce[%, be, Reals], {x1 > 0, x2 > 0, x3 > 0, x4 > 0, x5 > 0, x6 > 0, x7 > 0, 
    x8 > 0, x9 > 0, x10 > 0, x11 > 0, y > 0, 0 <= b <= 1, 0 <= be <= 1}] // ToRules
(* {b -> 0, ei -> (be (-1 + b + be) x7)/(-x6 + be (-1 + b + be) x7), 
    eu -> (be (-1 + b + ei - b ei) x7 + be^2 (x7 - ei x7) + x8)/(b x5 + x8)} *)
(* be -> 0 *)

Flatten@{nrule, erule[[2 ;; 3]]} //. {b -> 0, be -> 0}
(* {n -> 0, ei -> 0, eu -> 1} *)
```

as desired.  Finally, to confirm after all these computations that this solution is correct,

```
(List @@ eq) //. {n -> 0, ei -> 0, eu -> 1, b -> 0, be -> 0}
(* {True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68846/discussion-on-answer-by-bbgodfrey-solve-taking-a-long-time-to-solve-a-system-of).